# How can I solve "too few arguments to function App\Exports\ItemsExport::__construct(), 0 passed" in the export excel laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel, export, export-to-excel, laravel-5.6

I make export classes exportable in the App/Exports like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Repositories\ItemRepository;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
class ItemsExport implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;
    protected $itemRepository;
    public function __construct(ItemRepository $itemRepository)
    {
        $this->itemRepository = $itemRepository;
    }
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->itemRepository->getItem();
    }
}
```

I call from controller like this :

```
return (new ItemsExport)->download('items.xlsx');
```

There exist error like this :

```
too few arguments to function App\Exports\ItemsExport::__construct(), 0 passed
```

How can I solve this error?

I get export excel from this tutorial :https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/basics

Comment: Pass an argument to `new ItemsExport` ?

Comment: @Jerode Yes. Of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Laravel's dependency injection you need to construct the new instance via the application container:

```
return app()->make(ItemsExport::class)->download('items.xlsx');
```

This assumes that the applications knows how to construct the `ItemRepository`

Alternatively if this is in a controller action you can just inject it e.g.

```
public function controllerAction(ItemsExport $exporter) {
     return $exporter->download('items.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Your code works. But your code is not in the documentation. Can you show your script used to open excel? No download.  I tried to use the code in the documentation, same error

Comment: So I mean, Can you update your answer, how to open excel?

Comment: I try like this : `return $exporter->store('items.xlsx');` there exist error : `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`

Comment: `store` ? why would use store to send a response? You originally used `download` which looks more correct. Also this code has nothing to do with laravel-excel but with fundamentals of laravel itself.

Comment: I want when the function is executed, it will open the excel file. No download

Comment: I don't think an HTTP response can coerce the browser into launching an arbitrary application without the user actually setting it up to do that

Comment: That's why I asked how to set it up? If I can setting that, I will not ask

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572197/how-can-i-pass-parameter-in-the-laravel-excel