# How can I pass parameter in the laravel excel?

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-excel

I get tutorial from here : https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/basics

```
<?php
...
use App\Exports\ItemsDetailsExport;
class ItemController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function exportToExcel(ItemsDetailsExport $exporter, $id)
    {
        //dd($id); I get the result
        return $exporter->download('Summary Detail.xlsx');
    }
}
```

My export like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Repositories\Backend\ItemDetailRepository;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
class ItemsDetailsExport implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;
    protected $itemDetailRepository;
    public function __construct(ItemDetailRepository $itemDetailRepository)
    {
        $this->itemDetailRepository = $itemDetailRepository;
    }
    public function collection()
    {
        $test  = Input::get('id');
        dd('yeah', $test);
    }
}
```

I want to pass id parameter to export file. I try like that, but I don't get the id. The id is null

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use normal dependency injection when you have a specific parameter. This is what you can do though:

```
class ItemsDetailsExport implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;
    protected $itemDetailRepository;
    protected $id;
    public function __construct(ItemDetailRepository $itemDetailRepository, $id)
    {
        $this->itemDetailRepository = $itemDetailRepository;
        $this->id = $id; 
    }
    public function collection()
    {
        $test  = $this->id;
        dd('yeah', $test);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the container doesn't know how to resolve $id however there are two ways around this.

1. Manual passing of `$id`:

   ```
   public function exportToExcel($id)
   {
       $exporter = app()->makeWith(ItemsDetailsExport::class, compact('id'));   
       return $exporter->download('Summary Detail.xlsx');
   }
   ```
2. Route injection:

Define your route as:

```
 Route::get('/path/to/export/{itemExport}', 'ItemController@exportToExcel');
```

In your `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot() {
     parent::boot();
     //Bindings

     Route::bind('itemExport', function ($id) { //itemExport must match the {itemExport} name in the route definition
         return app()->makeWith(ItemsDetailsExport::class, compact('id'));   
     });
}
```

Then your route method is simplified as:

```
public function exportToExcel(ItemsDetailsExport $itemExport)
{
    //It will be injected based on the parameter you pass to the route
    return $itemExport->download('Summary Detail.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685886/how-can-i-add-title-and-sum-value-of-column-in-laravel-excel-version-3

Answer (score 12):

For passing data from controller to laravel excel function we can pass and use data like below

For example, we have to pass data year like **2019** we will pass like below

in controller

```
Excel::download(new UsersExport(2019), 'users.xlsx');
```

In laravel import file

```
class UsersExport implements FromCollection {
    private $year;

    public function __construct(int $year) 
    {
        $this->year = $year;
    }
    
    public function collection()
    {
        return Users::whereYear('created_at', $this->year)->get();
    }
}
```

you can refer all following official documentation link

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#plain-old-php-object

Comment: Great, this is the best solution